# Libertine (biolinum) font internal name

Tags: fonts, libertine

My document used the libertine package. My chapter titles are formatted to sans serif with `\sffamily` and the titlesec package. I'm assuming this means it uses biolinum font for my chapters. Now I want to change my document to lmodern but keep the biolinum chapter formatting. Since I am changing the `sffamily` to the lmodern variant (whatever it may be called) I need to use the `\fontfamily{<internalname>}\selectfont` command.

After browsing the libertine documentation and the libertine type1 .sty files I can not find the internal name for biolinum. I have tried `LinuxBiolinumO-LF` and this seems to work but gives a warning when combined with `\bfseries`, so I can not reproduce the bold formatting I had when I used sffamily under the libertine package. Any ideas on how to fix? I do not want to change the sfdefault.

Im using texlive 2012 with pdflatex. Thanks.

Comment: Yes that will allow me to use `\sffamily` again. But I mentioned a restriction: want to keep `lmss` as the `\sfdefault`. Maybe I can make a new command in the pramble giving me access to 2 `\sffamily` versions (lmss & biolinum)?

Comment: Well, yes, haha. Is it odd to want font control in pdflatex? The whole internal naming thing is strange if you ask me. Whish I could just use `{\biolinum text}` to change text to that font.

Comment: Try `\newcommand{\bioln}{%
   \fontfamily{LinuxBiolinumT-OsF}\selectfont}` and use `\bioln{text}` for desired results without invoking sf replacement, you can use default sf as it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, it is not that difficult; the problems arise more from the many options the `biolinum` family offers, which means there is no `\biolinum` command per se.

The following should allow you access to both types of sans serif:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{biolinum}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{lmss}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

{\sffamily\lipsum[1]}

{\sffamily\bfseries\lipsum[1]}

{\sffamily\bfseries\itshape\lipsum[1]}

\newpage
{\biolinumOsF\lipsum[1]} % compare \biolinumLF

{\biolinumOsF\bfseries\lipsum[1]}

{\biolinumOsF\bfseries\itshape\lipsum[1]}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems my libertine installation is a bit outdated. I can not use the biolinum package. So I tried with my `\usepackage{biolinum-type1}` but this does not contain any control sequence like the one you used. Guess I should update first then test again.

Comment: It should be `\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{lmss}`; don't redefine `\sffamily` that way.

Comment: @Jayvl -- In my 2012 copy of `biolinum-type1.sty` (dated 2013/02/13), there are the following, defined by `\DeclareTextFontCommand` (lines 156-158): `\liningnums`, `\biolinumOsF`, and `\biolinumLF`.  Is your copy different?

Comment: @Jon -- Yes my copy (2012/10/30) is different, it does not even have 50 lines.

Comment: @Jayvl -- Why not install either `libertine-legacy.tds.zip` or `libertine.tds.zip` from [here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/install/fonts)?  The `.tds.zip` files are super easy to install on TeX Live: either unzip them at the base of TEXMFHOME or TEXMFLOCAL (findable via the command `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME` or `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFLOCAL`).  The `.tds` indicates that it will unzip everything into the appropriate directories and/or create them if these directories don't exist.

Comment: I tried the manual libertine install in my texmf-local folder (followed by texhash+updmap), does not work properly. `\usepackage{libertine}` does not work anymore (seems to require `mweights.sty`). Further `\usepackage{biolinum}` does not give me output with your example. During compilation attempt it says non existant root file, but does not throw an error when it fails to produce a pdf. `biolinum.sty` does contain your macros, though around line 250 because it is more recent. The `*type1.sty` files are said to be obsolete. Perhaps I should have tried with `tlmgr` instead of manual...

Comment: But Jon I do think your answer is what I'm looking for. Though I didn't know biolinum had 2 types (makes me wonder which type it used for sffamily). Also: if I load lmodern last I dont need that `\renewcommand` line right?

Comment: I will make a new attempt at updating libertine tomorrow, if I can't solve that I'll make a new question. I'm pretty sure this(your example) will work once I fix it. And what I meant with 2 types was `biolinumOsF` vs `biolinumLF`. I also wonder if those convenient macros are available with other fonts. Or is the internal name still a fact of life...

Comment: @Jayvl -- Oh, I see: it is a matter of whether you want so-called Oldstyle Figures or Lining Figures.  Some fonts have both (e.g., Palatino or KP Fonts), but most don't.  (And I realize now what you mean about `mweights.sty`, which, yes, you should install if you are installing `libertine.sty`.)  Hopefully you get it up and running soon and without too much grief!

Comment: Update: It works for me now! Apparently the install required me to run `updmap --enable Map=libertine.map` instead of the `updmap-sys` variant.

Comment: @Jayvl -- Great.  It is true that you need to be careful as to which version of `updmap` you should use.  If I remember rightly, once you use one form, you need to stick to that one.